# jQuery selector not recognizing $(this) only $(element[name=foo])

Tags: jquery

I just came across this issue with jQuery. I have a pool of input radios/checkboxes and when their state change, a class should be added or removed. Since checkboxes are one or many, I need to check if all checkboxes are unchecked before removing the class. That's where I came across this issue that I solved, but have no idea why it doesn't work with my first try.

This does not work - it always returns length = 0 to me:

```
if ($(this).filter(':checked').length <= 0)
```

This works:

```
if ($('input[name="'+$(this).attr('name')+'"]').filter(':checked').length <= 0)
```

I have attached a Fiddle, so you can understand where I'm coming from. My question is, why can't I just reference length to $(this) when I can get anything else (type, name, etc) ?

http://jsfiddle.net/9XH37/2/

**PS: If this is a stupid/duplicate question, I'll delete it.**

Comment: Please don't delete a question, especially if someone takes the time to answer it. You never know who else might be wondering the same thing.

Comment: Some people are hostile to certain questions as well as when they may have a duplicate. I just wanted to make sure they're aware I'm not being lazy... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9XH37/5/)***

Use this

```
if ($(this).siblings(':checked').length <= 0)
```

instead of

```
if ($(this).filter(':checked').length <= 0)
```

Reason:

[.siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) looks for all the check-boxes which are siblings to the changed checkbox, where as [.filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) reduces the set of matched elements to those that match the selector.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I wasn't aware of siblings()... my solution works, I just need to understand why $(this) doesn't capture the is checked filter.

Comment: .filter() matches the exact selector, so `$(this).filter()` expects all the inputs to be the same selector. `if ($(".r0 input").filter(':checked').length <= 0)` this will also work.

Comment: "where as .filter reduces the set of matched elements to those that match the selector" - so this will only get the exact clicked checkbox? Even if it has the same name as my code?

Comment: @Fabi - exactly. it doesn't consider all the inputs.